# Tkinter label can't show the correct message(Win 10 python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I try to make a function, when user type the file name in inputField and click the save button. The mdb file can be copied with new Entry name, and the message will show source => destination. Turning to the same file name, it will show File has existed. But when I type the new file name, click the save button. It always show File has existed. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
from tkinter.ttk import *


class View(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.winfo_toplevel().title("Save File")
        self.grid()
        self.init_view()

    def init_view(self):
        self.inputText = Label(self)
        self.inputText["text"] = "Input Serial ID"
        self.inputText.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N + E)
        self.inputField = Entry(self)
        self.inputField["width"] = 20
        self.inputField.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N + W)

        self.save = Button(self)
        self.save["text"] = "Save"
        self.save.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N + W)

        self.displayText = Label(self)
        self.displayText["text"] = "Status:Idle"
        self.displayText.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=7, sticky=N)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = View(master=root)
    root.mainloop()
```

```
import shutil
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from Save_Server_View import View
from tkinter import Tk

year = datetime.now().year
month = datetime.now().month
src = r"HIDE FOR PRI"
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
dst = os.path.join(dir, ".\\data\\" + str(year) + "\\" + str(month))


# Controller
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = View(master=Tk())
        self.app.save["command"] = self.save_method
        self.app.mainloop()

    # Copy & Rename File
    def save_method(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
            for filename in files:
                if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(dst)):
                    message = (os.path.join(dst)), "not found"
                    self.app.displayText["text"] = message
                else:
                    first_src_file_path = os.path.join(src, '', filename)
                    new_dst_file_path = os.path.join(dst, '', self.app.inputField.get() + '.mdb')
                    new_dst_file_name = os.path.basename(new_dst_file_path)
                    try:
                        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(dst, new_dst_file_name)):
                            shutil.copy(first_src_file_path, new_dst_file_path)
                            message = 'source={} => destination={}'.format(src, dst)
                            self.app.displayText["text"] = message
                    except:
                        message = "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
                        self.app.displayText["text"] = message
                    else:
                        self.app.displayText["text"] = 'File has existed.'

# Execute
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Controller()
```

I except the message can be showed correct when file(with new name) copied to the destination file path. Then show 'source={} => destination={}'.format(src, dst)'. When the filename was same in the destination file path, it will show 'File has existed.'

Comment: You are not updating the content of `src` when you click `save` button.
`src` will always have `r"HIDE FOR PRI"`.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `src` contents when you click `save` button.
Just add the following line before the `for` loop in your `save_method`function.

```
src = self.app.inputField.get()
```

Comment: @Pruhdvi I think maybe this code lead to wrong direction. I still can't understand.

Comment: You mentioned it always showed File has existed, you are getting this error because the content in the src variable is not the text you are entering in the input field.

Comment: You are giving same name for all the files located in the folder, that's why you are getting this error